# Using unique values in other code

Tags: php, mysql

Please find the below code for more information.

```
 // Finding a list of schools.
    $schoolQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT stud_school AS schools FROM students";
    $schoolsList = mysqli_query($conn, $schoolQuery);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schoolsList)) {
    echo $row['schools'];
    }
    echo "<br>";
```

The code above is supposed to collect unique values in a column of my table in the database.

This is the output:

> ArkCCAPM (where Ark, CCA and PM are the school initials).

```
$allSchools = mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools']);
// Sums upp all the points recieved by each student for specific school
$myQuery = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS total FROM result WHERE stud_id IN (SELECT stud_id FROM students WHERE stud_school = 'CCA')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $myQuery);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Total CCA: ".$data['total'];
```

The code above calculates the total points for the school CCA only. 
What I want to do is use the unique values (which lists all the schools in my database) and implement that in to the calculation code above so it can work out the totals for not only CCA but all the schools listed in the unique values.
So the out put looks like this:

```
Total CCA: 16
Total PM: 17
Total Ark: 9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools'])` is failing you, and no idea why you would want to use that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of first querying for the list of schools, then using the returned result to get your final result through another query, you may *directly* use this unique query:

```
$myQuery = "
  SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS total, school
  FROM result
  JOIN students ON result.stud_id = students.stud_id
  GROUP BY school
";
```

Then use its result like you planned.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf3667/5/0)

NOTE: as already pointed by some comments, you have nothing to do with something like `$allSchools = mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools']);`: `mysqli_real_escape()` is used only *before writing to the DB*, not after reading from it!

Comment: @JayBlanchard You're right. I answered too quickly, with the idea that "directly" was explanatory enough, which may not be true for everybody. So I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: This code works, but it gives me the total points for the three schools together. Right now with your code above, the output looks like this:
Total: 42 This is the sum of all three schools. Is there a way in which I can use the distinct values to give me a total of the three schools separately so that the output looks like this:
Total CCA: 16
Total PM: 17
Total Ark: 9

Comment: @SubZero Sorry, I really answered too quickly! I modifed my answer: it's yet more simple (and now tested).

Comment: No it was fine, I learned something new from that code, plus thanks this new code works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$allSchools = mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools']);
// Sums upp all the points recieved by each student for specific school
$myQuery = "SELECT students.stud_school, SUM(result_studpoints) AS total FROM result JOIN students ON students.stud_id = result.stud_id GROUP BY students.stud_school";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $myQuery);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Total " . $data['stud_school'] . ": ".$data['total'] . "<br />";
```

Comment: same fail `mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools'])`

Comment: I have taken out the `mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools'])` and I have used the rest of the code mentioned above, and it does work the out put looks like this:
Total Ark: 9

It outputs the total points for one school and the total is correct but how can I also output the other two schools so the output looks like this:

Total Ark: 9 
Total CCA: 16
Total PM: 20

Comment: Try his code:

$myQuery = "SELECT students.stud_school, SUM(result_studpoints) AS total FROM result JOIN students ON students.stud_id = result.stud_id GROUP BY students.stud_school";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $myQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schoolsList)) {
 echo "Total " . $row['stud_school'] . ": ".$row['total'] . "<br />";
}

Comment: I used the code but this time there is nothing being output, I checked for syntax but still nothing is being output. Is there a way I can use the $schoolQuery as a variable and put the variable into the $myQuery statement where stud_school = VARIABLE ? From this would it be possible to output the in the format stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Finding a list of schools.
$schoolQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT stud_school AS schools FROM students";
$schoolsList = mysqli_query($conn, $schoolQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schoolsList)) 
{
    $allSchools = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['schools']);
    // Sums upp all the points recieved by each student for specific school
    $myQuery = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS total FROM result WHERE stud_id IN (SELECT stud_id FROM students WHERE stud_school = '$allSchools')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $myQuery);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "Schools: ".$row['schools']." --> Total CCA: ".$data['total'];
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($row['schools'])` will fail them.

Comment: I see you edited to use the connection parameter, but there really isn't any use for it, since there is no user interaction. They're fetching from a query.

Comment: No, you don't want a query inside a loop. Not necessary.